# Setting source IP with posix sockets

Tags: c, linux, networking, sockets, tcp

Is it possible for an application to request a socket (tcp) and have it set the source address without using raw sockets? (the addresses would be bound to the interfaces. [no spoofing]).
This would be a tcp client connection, not bind()ing to a specified address.

Comment: yes- but it requires a `bind` to interface.  Shouldn't this be on stackoverflow?

Comment: @tMC - not necessarily. There's no code (for example). I know it's not essential for Stack Overflow questions to have code, but that's certainly one vote against it being migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible without `bind` or raw sockets.